# Stata creating output for IV regression with bysort

Tags: stata

So I am running an 2SLS model by interview year and I have many interview years and different models. I want to present the first-stage results first and then after reassuring the reader that they are solid move on to the interesting results.

Example of Table A (first stage):

Year DV   Coef SE   F    N

1    A     0.5 0.1 100 1000

2    A     0.8 0.2 10 1500

3    B    -0.6 0.4 800 800

Table B with the main results would look the same just without the F-Stat.

I searched on the web about how to create those tables automatically in Stata, but despite finding many questions I didn't find an answer that worked for me. From those different posts and help-files I build something that is nearly there.

It creates the table I want for the main results with the F-Stat together by some variable (Step A in the code). However, when I move on to do the same for the first stage it only saves the last wave as I restore the estimates. I understand why Stata does it like that, but I cannot think of a way of convincing it to do what I want.

```
clear all

*Install user-written commands
ssc install outreg2, replace
ssc install ivreg210, replace

*load data
sysuse auto, clear

*run example model (obviously the model itself is bogus)
********************************************************
*Step A: creates the IV results by foreign plus the F-Statistic
bys foreign:  ///
    outreg2 using output1-IV-F, label excel stats(coef se) dec(2) adds(F-Test, e(widstat)) nocons nor2 keep(mpg) replace: ///
    ivreg210 price headroom trunk (mpg=rep78 ), savefirst first
*Step B: creates the first stage results in a seperate table
bys foreign:  ///
    ivreg210 price headroom trunk (mpg=rep78 ), savefirst first
    est restore _ivreg210_mpg   
    outreg2 using output1_1st-stage, replace keep(rep78)

cap erase output1-IV-F
cap erase output1_1st-stage
```

So ideally I would only run the model once and have the F-Stat in the first-stage table, but I can fix that manually. The biggest issue I have is how to store the estimates when using bysort. If anyone has any suggestions about that, I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
ssc install estout
```

then you can store whatever result you want for later use, even after a bysort.

```
eststo clear
sysuse auto, clear
bysort foreign: eststo: reg price weight mpg
esttab, label nodepvar nonumber
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! However, I do not understand how this answers the question?

Changing from outreg to eststo does not solve the issue that when using bysort stata only remembers the last estimation. See your own example here:

ssc install estout, replace
sysuse auto, clear
bys foreign :reg price mpg, robust
eststo my_result
esttab my_result /* you forgot a t in esttab */

Please let me know if I misunderstood something. I am happy to change to eststo if it is easier to do than with outreg2. Though, my guess is the issue is with how Stata stores estimation results.

Answer (score -1):

This is a round-about solution. It works, but really isn't the proper solution I was/am looking for. The "trick" is to run the 1st stage as a separate model.

```
clear all

*Install user-written commands
ssc install outreg2, replace
ssc install ivreg210, replace

*load data
sysuse auto, clear

*run example model (obviously the model itself is bogus)
********************************************************
*Step A: creates the IV results by foreign plus the F-Statistic
bys foreign:  ///
    outreg2 using output1-IV-F, label excel stats(coef se) dec(2) adds(F-Test, e(widstat)) nocons nor2 keep(mpg) replace: ///
    ivreg210 price headroom trunk (mpg=rep78 ), savefirst first

*Step B: creates the first stage results in a seperate table
bys foreign:  ///
    ivreg210 price headroom trunk (mpg=rep78 ), savefirst first
    est restore _ivreg210_mpg   
    outreg2 using output1_1st-stage1, replace keep(rep78)

*************   
/* NEW BIT */   
*************   
*Step C: creates the first stage results in a seperate table
bys foreign:  ///
    outreg2 using output1_1st_NEW, label excel stats(coef se) dec(2) nocons nor2 keep(rep78) replace: ///
    reg mpg headroom trunk rep78

cap erase output1-IV-F
cap erase output1_1st-stage1
cap erase output1_1st_NEW
```

Comment: forget about that brother. see my solution

Comment: see my explanation of why your solution doesn't work? I am happy to learn if you can explain why/how your solution answers the question I posed. Down voting me for solving my own problem and sharing it when you did not understand the problem in the first place is quite....